# Text Box on form must pick up data from another form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have two forms: frmReceipts and frmDiffs. frmReceipts has an unbound control that shows the result of this function:

```
Public Function RecDiffs() As Double

RecDiffs = Forms!frmDiffs.Text17

End Function
```

At the moment the value of Text17 is 54.00 but when frmReceipts opens it shows the value 0.00 on control Text41. I can correct this by clicking a command button that runs 
   Me.Form.Refresh

Refresh does not work (i.e. Text17 continues to show 0.00) if Refresh runs On Load, On Open, or On Activate. It only seems to work by clicking the command button. Ideally I'd like the correct value to show in Text17 simply when the form opens. Also, If I put frmReceipts into Design mode then back into Form View, Text17 then shows the correct data.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about which control is showing 0.00. Is it Text17, which you say is on your frmDiffs form, or is it the unbound control on frmReceipts? Perhaps edit the question and give us the name of the unbound control on frmReceipts throughout.

Comment: Done but problem now solved. FrmDiffs is sorted by a control "ClientName". Removing the sort procedure solved the problem. Don't know why - perhaps because at the moment there is only one record in frmDiffs.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
.Requery
```

Instead of refresh.

Answer (score 0):

define the Control Source of the unbound control in frmReceipts equal to

```
Control Source: =[Forms]![Form2]![Text0]
```

It will show the correct value.

You can also define your control as

```
enabled: false
locked: True
```

I checked your code (MS Access 2013) and it runs well, but if Text17 contains a string, you can have a conversion problem in your function.

Comment: Should I not downgrade because it didn't solve my particular problem? Just curious.

Comment: When an answer is useful and is 'voted up' the answerer receive +10 point reputation, when 'voted down' -2. Normally the answer is voted down when it is the least useful answer, a bad answer. 
The answer of Sixthsense was not a bad answer. Back to your problem: can you post a DB with the 2 forms to dropbox, so that I can investigate what is going wrong?

Comment: Text17 contains no strings - it's all numbers and summing of numbers. I'll post DB ASAP. It's very strange. I get a correct answer using Refresh only via a command button, not On Activate. I also get correct answer if I manually put the form into design mode then back to form view. Going into design via code doesn't work.

Comment: I had to remove some confidential data before posting the DB. In the course of this I removed OrderBy ClientName (redundant - from another form from which frmDiffs derives). So your comment has led to the answer. But why? This is all very curious to me - if you know why I'd be interested.

Comment: I have inputted your suggested procedure and mad the necessary changes. I get an error: 'Runtime error 2471. The expression you entered as a query parameter produced this error: "F0106144752"'. This is in response to this part of the code: 
varApplicantID = DLookup("DiscLookup", "tblForms", "RefNo=" & Me.Text0). I have triple-checked my changes to your code. F0106144752 is a genuine RefNo and is actually connected to an application.

Comment: Please disregard the above comment - relates to another question.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled across the answer: frmDiffs sorts records by 'ClientName'. Deleting that procedure solved the problem entirely. It might have been caused by the fact that at the moment there is only one record. Cisco had suggested I upload the database. I was deleting certain data prior to upload. This caused an error message relating to the OrderBy procedure, which I then deleted.